# clang-format option to insert new line in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, clang-format

My Angular application is written in TypeScript. I added a `clang-config` file to establish consistency in the code. After exploring the options I have the following block:

```
Language: JavaScript
BasedOnStyle: WebKit
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
ColumnLimit: 250
IndentWidth: 2
JavaScriptQuotes: Single
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
```

1. I like to code on alternate lines. Thus, a new line needs to exist between two valid JS statements. `MaxEmptyLinesToKeep` removes the newline before closing braces of a scope (but retains the one at the beginning). How do I set this?
2. The decorator options is now on a single line: `@Component({ selector : 'in... })` How do I get it to one key per line?
3. When changing the `BasedOnStyle` setting to `Mozilla`, the inner scope, i.e.: `Observable.subscribe(()=>{ // This region. })`, is indented with 2 spaces instead of 4. Which setting governs this?
4. Empty functions close on the next line. How do I close it on the same line, e.g.: `function foo() { }` instead of
   `function foo() {
   }`

Thanks!